# how to make a uber-like design for ios?

Tags: ios

I'd like to make an ios App. I like uber's design very much. But I am wondering how I can make one view controller on top of another view controller. So in the screen, we see one view controller's view fill most of screen, but we can see a small portion at the bottom of the parent view controller.

This way, when we click that small portion, we can easily switch to the parent view controller.

In the attached picture, black part belongs to a view controller, but the map belongs to the parent view controller.

Any suggestions for this ?

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions -> Any solution -> Any code !!!

Comment: What is uber? Needs more detail to be able to answer.

Comment: I don't use Uber. Could you at least show us what it looks like?

Comment: uber is a popular taxi App.

Comment: 'put on hold as off-topic by Vladimir, reecon, rdurand, Simon, gnat 54 mins ago' ? what's off-topic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to talk specifically about this image rather than the general case.

There are several ways to achieve this.

This could be a single view controller with a view hierarchy like...

```
- UIView
|
| - Map
|
| - Table View
```

In this case the map can be shown/hidden by just animating it into position.

Another way is to use a modal transition.

Take a [snapshot](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW198) of the map view and then use this snapshot as a background view of the next view controller by passing the view in...

```
UIView *snapshotView = [self.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];

modalTableViewController.snapshotBackgroundView = snapshotView;
```

Then in the `modalTableViewController` you can do something like...

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.snapshotBackgroundView atIndex:0];
```

to add the background view in.

Then you can detect a touch on this background and use it to dismiss the modal view...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

There are many ways to achieve it though.

Comment: In general, I agree with using transition delegates and using a snapshot to cut the "from" view in 2, and make it appear as if the view itself is splitting. After inspecting the views and transitions in Uber with Spark Inspector however, I found that this is basically one big view controller. The map view you see anchored at the bottom of the menu is actually the real map, which has animated down and then animates back up. There are no snapshots involved. This makes animating between them easier as there is no switch in view controllers.